# Eclipse: "Users" tab is missing in local server

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Recently I copied my Eclipse workspace to new PC. And now I have problems with Servers that was previous deffined in Eclipse.

When I am double-clicking on local Java EE 6 Web Profile Server then I can't see "Users" tab there:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rw11yer4cghh78e/server%20%28previous%29.png?dl=0

But when I create new local server in Eclipse then "Users" tab is there:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dggu243jogratxq/server%20new.png?dl=0

Can anyone know what is going wrong and how to fix it? I do not want to re-create server and add all my apps on it. I want to use my previous deffined server (existing) and fix this missing "Users" tab issue.

If you need more information, please let me know.

BR, Kristaps

Comment: I'm not sure about this solution, but you could give it a try: Open old workspace and export your preferences - `File > Export > Preferences (Present under "General")`. It will be saved in a file.

Now open your new workspace and import this preference file: `File > Import > Preferences`

Comment: Hi,
I do not have my old pc (old workspace) available. Is there any other solution to add missing "Users" tab?

Comment: Sorry, but have no other clue.